# Pandas rolling window: developing rule based on window values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I'm working on a neonatal project with the long story short of it being that neonates are assigned a certain score based on symptoms they have at a given time point, and based on how their scores change over time, we decide whether to increase medicine dosages, keep them the same, or wean them off. We denote these 3 states numerically as either +1 (increase), 0 (maintain), or -1 (weaning). The rules to decide what to do are as follows:

- Increase dosage if sum of 3 consecutive scores >= 24 OR a single score is >= 12.
- Maintain dose if you don't meet the rules for either increase or decrease dosages
- Lower dose if there's at least 48 hours without needing to increase dose, the sum of the 3 most recent scores is <18, AND no single score is >8.

With help from people here, we have code that accounts for increasing dosages and maintaining dosages. However, I'm struggling to write the rule to determine how to lower dosages. Here's a sample of code we have:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'baby': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','B','B'],
   'dateandtime':  ['8/2/2009  5:00:00 PM', '7/19/2009  5:00:00 PM', '7/19/2009  5:00:00 PM', '7/17/2009  6:00:00 AM','7/17/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/14/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/19/2009  5:00:00 AM', '7/16/2009  9:00:00 PM','7/19/2009  9:00:00 AM', '7/14/2009  6:00:00 PM', '7/15/2009  3:04:00 PM', '7/20/2009  5:00:00 PM','7/16/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/18/2009  1:00:00 PM', '7/16/2009  6:00:00 AM', '7/13/2009  9:00:00 PM','7/19/2009  1:00:00 AM','7/15/2009  12:04:00 AM'],
   'score':  [6, 3, 3, 5, 10, 14, 5, 4, 11, 4, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 12, 6, 6]
    })

df.dateandtime = pd.to_datetime(df['dateandtime']) # change column type for ease of indexing
df = df.set_index('dateandtime')
df.sort_index(inplace = True)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()] #Remove any duplicated rows

#Calculate conditions
df['sum_3_scores'] = df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling(3).sum().reset_index(0,drop=True)
df['max_1_score'] = df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling(1).max().reset_index(0,drop=True)

#you don't nead to calculate the 24hr mean because the 48hr max is 8 the 24hr mean will also be < 8 
#df['mean_24hr_score'] = df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling('24h').mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)

#scoring logic
def score(data):
    if data['sum_3_scores'] >= 24 or data['max_1_score'] >= 12:
        return 1
    return 0

df['rule'] = df.apply(score, axis = 1)

df.reset_index().set_index(['baby','dateandtime']).sort_index()
print(df)
```

This produces a nice dataframe that has what I want (with the exception of the rule for decreasing dosages):

```
                    baby  score  sum_3_scores  max_1_score  rule
dateandtime                                                     
2009-07-13 21:00:00    B     12           NaN         12.0     1
2009-07-14 00:01:00    A     14           NaN         14.0     1
2009-07-14 18:00:00    B      4           NaN          4.0     0
2009-07-15 00:04:00    B      6          22.0          6.0     0
2009-07-15 15:04:00    B      4          14.0          4.0     0
2009-07-16 00:01:00    B      7          17.0          7.0     0
2009-07-16 06:00:00    B      6          17.0          6.0     0
2009-07-16 21:00:00    A      4           NaN          4.0     0
2009-07-17 00:01:00    A     10          28.0         10.0     1
2009-07-17 06:00:00    A      5          19.0          5.0     0
2009-07-18 13:00:00    B      4          17.0          4.0     0
2009-07-19 01:00:00    B      6          16.0          6.0     0
2009-07-19 05:00:00    A      5          20.0          5.0     0
2009-07-19 09:00:00    A     11          21.0         11.0     0
2009-07-19 17:00:00    A      3          19.0          3.0     0
2009-07-20 17:00:00    B      6          16.0          6.0     0
2009-08-02 17:00:00    A      6          20.0          6.0     0
```

What's an easy way to program the rule for lowering the dosages? I understand I can do the 48h window with the code df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling('48h'), but it's not clear to me how to check the sum of only the 3 most recent dosages of that window

Comment: When you say `a single score is >= 12` and `no single score is >8` what timeframe are you speaking of?

Comment: @Dames To the best of my knowledge, "a single score is >=12" means when the score is 12 during at any time ever. "No single score is >8" should be within the 48 hour window.

Comment: So when there is a score >= 12 today you will increase tomorrow and the day after tomorrow and in a week you will look at today and say well that score was over 12 so we need to increase? You might want to say score >= 12 since the last increase?

Comment: @Dames So generally a score is taken every 4 hours. So if a score is >=12 at a time point, I increase the dose at that time point. I'll then check the score in 4 more hours and then either increase the dose again or maintain it depending on what my next score is

Comment: Okay I think I got it, I'll craft something for you

Comment: @Dames Thank you buddy I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'baby': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','B','B'],
   'dateandtime':  ['8/2/2009  5:00:00 PM', '7/19/2009  5:00:00 PM', '7/19/2009  5:00:00 PM', '7/17/2009  6:00:00 AM','7/17/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/14/2009  12:01:00 AM', '7/19/2009  5:00:00 AM', '7/16/2009  9:00:00 PM','7/19/2009  9:00:00 AM', '7/14/2009  6:00:00 PM', '7/15/2009  3:04:00 PM', '7/20/2009  5:00:00 PM','7/16/2009, 12:01:00 AM', '7/18/2009  1:00:00 PM', '7/16/2009  6:00:00 AM', '7/13/2009  9:00:00 PM','7/19/2009  1:00:00 AM','7/15/2009  12:04:00 AM'],
   'score':  [6, 3, 3, 5, 10, 14, 5, 4, 11, 4, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 12, 6, 6]
    })

df.dateandtime = pd.to_datetime(df['dateandtime']) # change column type for ease of indexing
df = df.set_index('dateandtime')
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()] #Remove any duplicated rows
```

I'm going to use a `.diff()` on a `.groupby()` thrice. When inspecting `max_last3` and `sum_last3` and `last48h_any_critical` manually I recommend to sort by `baby` and `dateandtime`:

```
# this helps
df = df.sort_values(by=['baby', 'dateandtime'])
# this is okay too
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

To get the sum of the last 3 values first group by baby then get rolling windows of 3 and then get the sum of each window.
**Important:** If the first two values are e.g. 12, 13 the sum of these 2 are >= 24 but no window of size 3 can be built! So the value would be `NaN` and `(Nan >= 24) == False`. To allow building incomplete windows use `min_periods=1`.

```
sum_last3 = df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum()
df['sum_last3'] = sum_last3.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

df['sum_last3_critical'] = df['sum_last3'] >= 24
df['sum_last3_good'] = df['sum_last3'] < 18
```

I'm still not sure if you want to look at all scores, the last 3 scores or only the very last score. This implementations detects an value >= 12 in the last 3 scores. Alternate solutions at the end.

```
max_last3 = df.groupby('baby')['score'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).max()
df['max_last3'] = max_last3.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

df['max_last3_ciritical'] = df['max_last3'] >= 12
df['max_last3_good'] = df['max_last3'] < 8
```

Now you can build a `critical` column, which indicates wether the dosis **must** be increased.

```
df['critical'] = df['sum_last3_critical'] | df['max_last3_ciritical']
```

Now you can get a time windows of 48 hours and get the maximum value of the critical columns (1.0 if True, 0.0 if False). You would ideally be using `.any()` but this does not exist for a `GroupBy` Object. As `.max()` returns a numeric value convert back to boolean afterwards.

```
last48h_any_critical = df.groupby('baby').rolling('48h')['critical'].max().astype('bool')
df['last48h_good'] = ~last48h_any_critical.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Now you can get wether the baby is in good condition and the dosis should be decreased.

```
df['good'] = df['last48h_good'] & df['sum_last3_good'] & df['max_last3_good']
```

To get a action value just subtract the `good` column from the `critical` column.

```
df['action'] = df['critical'].astype(int) - df['good'].astype(int)
```

The resulting DataFrame looks like this:

```
                    baby  score  sum_last3  sum_last3_critical  sum_last3_good  max_last3  max_last3_ciritical  max_last3_good  critical  last48h_good   good  action
dateandtime
2009-07-14 00:01:00    A     14       14.0               False            True       14.0                 True           False      True         False  False       1
2009-07-16 21:00:00    A      4       18.0               False           False       14.0                 True           False      True         False  False       1
2009-07-17 00:01:00    A     10       28.0                True           False       14.0                 True           False      True         False  False       1
2009-07-17 06:00:00    A      5       19.0               False           False       10.0                False           False     False         False  False       0
2009-07-19 05:00:00    A      5       20.0               False           False       10.0                False           False     False          True  False       0
2009-07-19 09:00:00    A     11       21.0               False           False       11.0                False           False     False          True  False       0
2009-07-19 17:00:00    A      3       19.0               False           False       11.0                False           False     False          True  False       0
2009-08-02 17:00:00    A      6       20.0               False           False       11.0                False           False     False          True  False       0
2009-07-13 21:00:00    B     12       12.0               False            True       12.0                 True           False      True         False  False       1
2009-07-14 18:00:00    B      4       16.0               False            True       12.0                 True           False      True         False  False       1
2009-07-15 00:04:00    B      6       22.0               False           False       12.0                 True           False      True         False  False       1
2009-07-15 15:04:00    B      4       14.0               False            True        6.0                False            True     False         False  False       0
2009-07-16 00:01:00    B      7       17.0               False            True        7.0                False            True     False         False  False       0
2009-07-16 06:00:00    B      6       17.0               False            True        7.0                False            True     False         False  False       0
2009-07-18 13:00:00    B      4       17.0               False            True        7.0                False            True     False          True   True      -1
2009-07-19 01:00:00    B      6       16.0               False            True        6.0                False            True     False          True   True      -1
2009-07-20 17:00:00    B      6       16.0               False            True        6.0                False            True     False          True   True      -1
```

### Alternative Options

If instead of looking at the last three values you want to look at all previous values. Use `expanding` instead.

```
# ideally change name of max_last3 to something like max_alltime
max_last3 = df.groupby('baby')['score'].expanding().max()
df['max_last3'] = max_last3.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

df['max_last3_ciritical'] = df['max_last3'] >= 12
df['max_last3_good'] = df['max_last3'] < 8
```

And if you instead want to look at only the last value you can directly compare to `score`:

```
# ideally change name of max_last3_ciritical to something like last_ciritical
df['max_last3_ciritical'] = df['score'] >= 12
df['max_last3_good'] = df['score'] < 8
```

Comment: So this is definitely a different way to go about it than I expected haha. To answer your question, if any time point ever has a score of >=12, dosage must be increased (high score = baby in bad shape). I think there is a small issue in the code because if I look at baby A (time stamp = 2009-07-16 21:00:00), your output says to increase the dosage when baby has a score of 4 at that point. I don't believe the dosage should be increased there because the score is <12 and the sum of the scores up to the point is 14+4 = 18, which is less than the required 24.

Comment: Baby A at 2009-07-16 21:00:00 is marked as `critical` as `max_last3_critical` is true as at least one of the last three values is >= 12. As I understand you want to use the second alternative option instead. Run the code with that bit exchanged and you will get your desired result.